# 415 Unsupported Media Type in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I doing delete function to delete banner image. I have create a delete function as below:

```js
    const [del, setDel] = useState([]);

    const DeleteBanner = async (banner) => {
        setDel(banner);
        console.log(del);
        Axios.delete(`/shop/${shopID}/banners`, del)
          .then((res) => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
              setMessage({
                data: `${res.data.MESSAGE}`,
                type: "alert-success",
              });
              onShowAlert();
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            setMessage({
              data: err.response.data.MESSAGE,
              type: "alert-danger",
            });
            setLoading(false);
            onShowAlert();
          });
      };
return (
<div className="">
                {shopData.data.ShopBanner.map((banners) => (
                  <Col
                    md="6"
                    xs="12"
                    className="p-0 m-0"
                    key={`img-${banners}`}
                    href="#pimage"
                  
                  >
                    <img
                      className="border border-white"
                      key={`img-${banners}`}
                      src={`/api/v2/public/Shop/${shopID}/banner/${encodeURIComponent(
                        banners
                      )}`}
                      style={{ padding: "5px" }}
                      width="100%"
                      height="100%"
                      alt="banner"
                    />
                    <Button
                      className="btn-link"
                      value={banners}
                      onClick={(e) => {
                        DeleteBanner(e.target.value);
                      }}
                    >
                      Delete
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                ))}
              </div>
)
```

then I display the banner image from the database and add a delete button set the value to banners (which is the image id )

the pic from swagger
[image]

when I try to delete, I'm getting the error 415 Unsupported Media Type, I'm not sure what went wrong. The post method for post the banner image is in fromdata which I success to post but has problem in delete

Comment: add sample in codesandbox for debugging is better

Comment: Check your backend controller for delete, it must be the correct method. Otherwise, try the same action using the POST method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axios accepts two parameters: `url` and optional `config`. You can use `config.data` to set the response body as follows:
 Refer : https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/897

```
axios.delete(URL, {
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  },
  data: del
});
```